# Messages are not sent to groups signalr

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, signalr

having some troubles with messages in signalr, cant get working with groups, so it work when it have like this form:

```
Clients.All.received(new { sender = sender, message = message, isPrivate = false });
```

In my project I've rooms, so when I'try to send messages to group they are not shown on a page:

```
Clients.Group(chatuser.CurrentGroup).received(new { sender = sender, message = message, isPrivate = false });
```

Here the small part of javascript:

```
chatHub.client.received = function (message) {
        viewModel.messages.push(new Message(message.sender, message.message, message.isPrivate, 'normalMessage'));
    };
```

Please just tell me if you need to see more code, i'll update all my code of chathub and model for it with a full file of javascript.

**UPDATE 2.**
ChatUser:

```
public ChatUser(string group) {
    CurrentGroup = group;
}

public ChatUser()
    : this("Lobby")
{

}

public string nameOfGroup { get; set; }
public int authorID { get; set; }

public List<string> chatGroup { get; set; }
public string CurrentGroup { get; set; }

public string userLogin { get; set; }
public HashSet<string> ConnectionIds { get; set; }
```

Chathub.cs

```
private void SendGroupMessage(ChatUser user, string message)
    {
        Clients.Group(user.CurrentGroup).received(user.userLogin, message);
    }

public void Send(string message)
{
    var user = GetUser(Context.User.Identity.Name);   
    SendGroupMessage(user, message);
}
public override Task OnConnected()
{

    string userName = Context.User.Identity.Name;
    string connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;

    var user = chatUsers.GetOrAdd(userName, _ => new ChatUser
    {
        userLogin = userName,
        ConnectionIds = new HashSet<string>()
    });

    lock (user.ConnectionIds)
    {

        user.ConnectionIds.Add(connectionId);

        // Or you might want to only broadcast this info if this
        // is the first connection of the user
        if (user.ConnectionIds.Count == 1)
        {

            Clients.Others.userConnected(userName);
        }
    }

    return base.OnConnected();
}

public Task JoinGroup(string groupName)
{
    var user = GetUser(Context.User.Identity.Name);
    string connectionGrpToString = user.ConnectionIds.ToString();

    //Join new Group
    user.CurrentGroup = groupName;
    //await
    return Groups.Add(connectionGrpToString, user.CurrentGroup);
}

public Task LeaveRoom(string roomName)
{
    var user = GetUser(Context.User.Identity.Name);
    string connectionGrpToString = user.ConnectionIds.ToString();
    var oldGroup = user.CurrentGroup;

    //Tell everyone user is leaving
    var message = string.Format("{0} has left.", user.userLogin);
    SendGroupAlert(user, message);

    //remove user from the group
    //await
    return Groups.Remove(connectionGrpToString, oldGroup); ;
}
```

A small part of reworked Chat.js:

```
function Message(from, msg, template) {
    this.from = ko.observable(from);
    this.message = ko.observable(msg);
    this.template = ko.observable(template);
}

    chatHub.client.received = function (sender, message) {
        // Add the message to the page.
        viewModel.messages.push(new Message(sender, message, 'normalMessage'));
    };
```

And view of chat.cshtml:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-search">
        <input type="text" id="txtMsg" class="input-xxlarge" disabled="disabled" placeholder="send" />
        <button type="button" id="btnSend" class="btn btn-info" disabled="disabled">Send</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-10">
    <ul id="normalMessage" data-bind="foreach: messages">
        <li>
            <strong><span data-bind="text: from"></span>: </strong>
            <span data-bind="text: message"></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Update 3.**
Maybe i'm missed something but also to show the code of room page and how it redirect me, also I've found that when I'm choose room which I want to join, it go to method `JoinGroup` and in parameter `groupName` it correctly show what I've choosed, but after when i'm going to send message, in `user.CurrentGroup` it show me default Lobby..

Rooms.cshtml:

```
<div id="nav">
    <div id="rooms" class="well well-small">
        <ul class="nav nav-list">
            <li class="nav-header">Rooms</li>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <li data-value=@item.Name>@Html.ActionLink("Room: " + item.Name, "Chat", "Home")</li>
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And how i'm join it in chat.js:

```
    var roomKey = $(this).data('value');
    chatHub.server.joinGroup(roomKey);
```

Comment: How are you establishing groups? Please share your `OnConnected` method. Also, what is `chatuser.CurrentGroup`? Please share this value

Comment: Post your code of assigning user to group.

Comment: I have update my code, sorry that took so long to reply, @salniro I've enother page which show the list of rooms. 'chatuser.CurrentGroup' It's store the group, which i've currently join, I'm declare it in ChatUser model.

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi Already posted :)

Comment: @salniro I've been found a new bug, check please in a thread.

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi I've been found a new bug, check please in a thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is this part and problem is logical error

```
public Task JoinGroup(string groupName)
{
    var user = GetUser(Context.User.Identity.Name);
    string connectionGrpToString = user.ConnectionIds.ToString();

    //Join new Group
    user.CurrentGroup = groupName;
    //await
    return Groups.Add(connectionGrpToString, user.CurrentGroup);
}
```

Here your fetech user info then assign group name into it then add user to that group.

All is fine but you forget to update your user list with group name .

You assign group name

```
    //Join new Group
    user.CurrentGroup = groupName;
```

but in your list still user don't have the group name in

```
    //Join new Group
    user.CurrentGroup = groupName;
```

When you pull user in send method from `GetUser`

```
public void Send(string message)
{
    var user = GetUser(Context.User.Identity.Name);   
    SendGroupMessage(user, message);
}
```

Groupname of user won't find as you didn't update groupname in userlist